# How to skip footer in csv file while reading with pandas read_csv and chunksize option

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm reading big csv files using pandas.read_csv() and chunksize = 500000.
Since I'm using chunksize so "skipfooter=1" option doesn't work with chunksize as it returns a generator instead of dataframe.

What's the best way to skip footer record from the file while reading in chunks?

Comment: Why can't you just subset them out after the fact?

Comment: Not sure how to keep track of the last chunk to remove footer lines.

Comment: You want to remove the footer for each chunk?

Comment: No, only from the last chunk.Footer is the last record of the entire file which is more than 3GB in size.

Comment: I'm saying that after you read everything in, just drop the footer.

Comment: I'm not storing/collecting entire dataset, I'm reading each chunk and inserting in Mysql table but I've to make sure the last chunk should not contain the footer. Hope that helps to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
import pandas

chunksize = 5
csv = pandas.read_csv('sample.csv', chunksize=chunksize)

class NextIterator:
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self._iterator = iterator
        self._buffer = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    @property
    def has_next(self):
        try:
            self._buffer = [next(self._iterator)]
            return True
        except StopIteration:
            return False

    def __next__(self):
        if self._buffer:
            return self._buffer.pop()
        else:
            # returns the dataframe
            return next(self._iterator)

has_next = True
b = NextIterator(csv)
while has_next:
    a = next(b)
    if b.has_next:
        print(a)
    else:
        print(a[:-1])
        has_next = False
```

You don't necessarily need to create a class, but I found it useful.

Using next and catching the `StopIteration` you can check if there is more in your iterator. And if there isn't you can just slice your chunk to exclude the last element.